# Google Lighthouse and SVGs with preserveAspectRatio="none"

Tags: google, page-speed, svg, lighthouse

Google Lighthouse has a *red triangle error* which significantly impacts the **Best Practices** score:

- **Displays images with incorrect aspect ratio**

I can understand why this would be regarded as an error with fixed-dimension raster images (and also with standard SVG vector images with explicitly set dimensions).

But in this case I'm displaying a small number of SVG flags on a webpage and the SVG flags display with certain dimensions in one part of the page and different dimensions in another part.

To enable using the same single SVG even when multiple instances of that SVG display with different dimensions, I use the attribute:

```
preserveAspectRatio="none"
```

This explicitly means (I would hope) that there is *no incorrect aspect ratio*.

But Google Lighthouse raises the error above, nevertheless.

At normal desktop browser size the graphics are quite small (either `27px x 27px` or `27px x 18px`) so, yes, I could potentially replace them with `.png` or `.webp` images.

But then I'd also need to bear in mind that the flag-image dimensions *also* increase in size very slightly at narrower responsive design breakpoints, so I would need a full set of fixed-dimension raster images for *each* breakpoint.

Is there any way I can instruct Google Lighthouse to ignore aspect ratio for SVG images which explicitly state `preserveAspectRatio="none"`?

Comment: Can't you just ignore this report of a problem?

Comment: Of course. But - at present, at least - I'm trying to go beyond that.